# event.toElement in IE8 and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, dom-events

I have noticed that in Chrome and IE9, for `onmouseout` events there is an `event.toElement` property (so you can determine which element the mouse is now pointing at).

I can not find a comparable property in Firefox.

Unfortunately I can not use jQuery to handle these events, I have to use native js.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just as a side note, in jQuery it would be http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/ as in Firefox.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that @BarnabasSzabolcs.  here in 2018, e.relatedTarget and $(e).relatedTarget are null and undefined respectively

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of event.toElement you should use this:

```
event.target
```

Comment: This answer is the one that worked for me. currentTarget and relatedTarget can give you different results. e.g. in a click event for an <a> when <ul><li><a></a></i></ul> e.target gives me <a> (just as e.toElement), but currentTarget and relatedTarget gives me the entire <ul>.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'm newish to javascript so I don't know why I was even using "toElement" probably some code example I saw somewhere. Target is clearly what I wanted in the first place.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Here is a good example if you also want to get Webkit/Chrome's localName https://gist.github.com/aubreypwd/748ba5958ae3fde694a2

Comment: Isn't target the element were the mouse *leaves from* ? toElement would be the elemtn where the mouse *leaves to* so the answer would be wrong?

Answer (score 25):

In Firefox it is `event.relatedTarget` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:event.relatedTarget#1003983

Comment: Since you realized that `IE` does have `event.toElement`, please remove it's reference from the question and answer to avoid the confusion... doing so won't invalidate any other existing answers.

Comment: FYI - IE11 does not appear to have `event.toElement`

Comment: Please use Azam Alvi's answer .target is prefered.

Answer (score 11):

I met a issue when I use Jay's answer, `event.target` on firefox points to the parent element of `event.toElement`'s target on chrome.
After looking into the event obj, I find `event.originalEvent.target`, it works good on both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 8):

Actually `event.currentTarget` should work in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: event.currentTarget is returning me the element the event belongs to, not the element that is being interacted with.  You can use event bubbling for example to define an event on a parent element so you don't have to attach similar event handlers to all child elements.

Comment: yeah why on earth doesn't FF have a toElement :(

Answer (score 7):

As of 2014, IE11 doesn't support `toElement`, I looked through the event object and found `target` to have the same data as toElement.

That is to say, if you click on a child element inside an element that this event triggered on, the child element will be the 'target' and stored in this attribute.

The element the event fired from is stored in the `currentTarget` attribute.

Note, I've only tested this for ie 11 so older versions may not support this.

So to support firefox ie and chrome (and possibly others, a polyfill would be necessary, something like:

```
var target = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget || e.target || function () { throw "Failed to attach an event target!"; }
```

Where `e` is the `event`

Comment: any benefit to this vs just using e.target?

Answer (score 0):

code easy to follow..

```
enter code here
if(typeof evt.toElement !== "undefined")
{
        evt.toElement.classList.toggle('done');
}
else if(typeof evt.relatedTarget !== "undefined")
{
    if(evt.relatedTarget !== null)
    {
        evt.relatedTarget.classList.toggle('done');
    }
    else if(typeof evt.currentTarget !== "undefined")
    {
        evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle('done');
    }
    else
    {
    console.log("s_f_li_clickexception...");    
    } //endif
} //endif
```

Comment: I think is more efficient to do evt.toElement = thesupportedFunction just one time then use the evt.toElement