# Make Bootstrap Popover Clickable / SetTimeout Use

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make bootstrap's 'popover' clickable in that it remains open when I hover into it.

I've managed to get this working with this script http://jsfiddle.net/CtuRx/5/.

But when I run it through jslint it complains that the settimeout is used before it's defined.

Wondering if someone can provide/explain a better solution to creating and using one function - to define and call a settimeout delay on both the mouseleave of the original .btn class and the .popover.

Thanks!

Comment: What is keepPopover supposed to do? It is undefined when you use it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an alternate solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FpsAc/4/).

I wrapped your buttons in divs.

When the mouse enters the wrapper div, it shows the popover and expands itself to provide a bridge for the mouse to enter the popover without triggering a mouseleave. We also put a mouseleave on the popover so that the wrapper div returns to its default width when we leave the popover.

```
links.mouseenter(function (event) {

    var link = $(this);
    link.popover('show').width(180);

    $('.popover').mouseleave(function () {
        link.popover('hide').width(defaultWidth);
    });   
});
```

When the mouse leaves the button and enters the bridge to the popover, I noticed the mouseleave event fires on the wrapper due to bubbling of the event. The following code fixes that by ignoring the mouse event unless we are exiting the wrapper to the body.

```
links.mouseleave(function (event) {
    if (event.toElement === document.body) {
        $(this).popover('hide').width(defaultWidth);
    }           
});
```

Try adding a border to the wrapper divs to see the code in action. Also. you should consider spacing out your CSS to make it more readable.

Comment: Seems like `event.toElement` is not supported in Firefox. You can additionally use `event.relatedTarget` as in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8600281/659910).