# Homemade jQuery Tooltip Script acting wonky

Tags: jquery

Here's my script: http://jsfiddle.net/w3kXj/2/

As you can see, I'm trying to make a checkbox input reveal the `.terms-of-use` div on hover. However, the behavior of the div is very unpredictable. Sometimes it does not show at all on hover, especially when you mouseover from underneath. What the heck is going on? Can anyone help?

Comment: Just an FYI , even if it would work, it is not that nice on   tablet, Something to keep in mind these days.

Comment: True enough. jQuery animations tend to suck on iPads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the intention should be to bind the listener to the whole fieldset instead of both elements separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/jomikr/w3kXj/10/

Comment: Good call, that eliminated all of the jumpiness. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use stop(true,true)  [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to fix that issue of the div fading all the way out but it still acts a little weird.

```
$(function(){
// email results page tooltip hover
    $('.terms-of-use').hide();
    $('.agree-statement, .terms-of-use').hover(function(){
        $('.terms-of-use').stop(true,true).fadeToggle(); 
    });   
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3kXj/5/

I would recommend using this plugin [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: Good call, and nice use of `fadeToggle()`, hadn't seen that. Jomikr's answer solved the issue more effectively, but yours taught me about `stop()` parameters and `fadeToggle()`, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By listening for hover and hover out on both the tooltip trigger and the tooltip itself, you're introducing many possible issues.  The solution is as follows:

- Listen for `mouseenter` on only `.agree-statement`
- Listen for `mouseleave` on both `.agree-statement` and `.terms-of-use`
- In the `mouseleave` handler, **only hide** if the [`toElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600174/event-toelement-in-ie8-and-firefox) isn't the tooltip itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working a little better.

http://jsfiddle.net/w3kXj/9/

Comment: That example doesn't work because `mousein()` isn't a function. Also, the div doesn't remain when you hover over it.