# event.toElement is undefined with onbeforedeactivate under IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to access the `event.toElement` property when the `beforedeactivate` event occurs, but it is returning `undefined` under IE9. It seems to work under IE8. The code below is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
$('#myButton').bind('beforedeactivate', myHandler);

function myHandler(event)
{
  var target = event.originalEvent.toElement;
}
```

Can't seem to find much information on this issue so I was wondering if someone can explain why this is happening or suggest a workaround for the problem?

Comment: I have never dealt with that event, but how about `relatedTarget` maybe?

Comment: @MaxArt I agree - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600174/event-toelement-in-ie8-and-firefox

Comment: @MaxArt: the problem is relatedTarget is also undefined for this event under IE9. What I'm trying to do is prevent the focus to be moved out of some buttons if the user clicks on certain targets. I was able to cancel the blur event from occurring for these buttons by cancelling the beforedeactivate event under IE7 and IE8. It is not working for IE9 however.

Comment: IE9 broke this, vote on connect to get it fixed: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785430/event-toelement-is-undefined-for-onbeforedeactivate-handler