# How can I detect the style element onclick from within the external JS file?

Tags: jquery

I have fairly limited knowledge of JS, but we have an action on the page which leads to an if statement in the external js file. I am using (event.toElement) which works in chrome but not ie, ff or opera.

inline js

```
    $("div#jquery-live-search .dialog-iframe-card").dialog2IFrame(  { 
            height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,
}); 

    $("div#jquery-live-search .dialog-iframe-report").dialog2IFrame(    { 
                height:900,
                  closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
                  closeOnEscape: true, 
                  removeOnClose: true, 
                  showCloseHandle: true,
    }); 
    });
```

external js

```
var parentHtml = "";
            if ($(event.toElement).hasClass("dialog-iframe-card")) {
            parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_CARD);
            } else if ($(event.toElement).hasClass("dialog-iframe-report")) {
            parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_REPORT);
            }
```

parentHTML has a variable at the start of the js file, which is loaded when the if statement makes the switch. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the correct action to the external file whilst working in a browser other than chrome.

I also tried the following which only worked on chrome ...

```
var $target = $(event.target);
                if ($target.hasClass("dialog-iframe-card")) {
                parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_CARD);
                } else if ($target.hasClass("dialog-iframe-report")) {
                parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_REPORT);
                }
```

> This question is not a duplicate as the suggested answer does not
>   solve the issue. [Suggested fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600174/event-toelement-in-ie8-and-firefox) does not fix the question, thanks.

Comment: how is the external js invoked

Comment: Do you mean what is the path?
We simply include the file <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/modal/jquery.dialog2.js"></script> and when a link with the class dialog-iframe-report or dialog-iframe-card is clicked the event is called via $("div#jquery-live-search .dialog-iframe-report").dialog2IFrame(    {  @ArunPJohny

Comment: `var $target = $(event.target);` should work in all browsers. The thing to take care for is that Chrome automatically populates `event`variable in a callback whereas in other browsers you explicitly have mention `event` in callback function's parameter

Comment: @UmairP thanks for the feedback, as you can see I have already tried var $target = $(event.target); in the external js file. It works in chrome but no other browsers.

Comment: Can you please post the complete function that has `var $target = $(event.target);`