# Jquery Drag and drop not working in Firefox, works fine in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

Jquery Drag and drop not working in Firefox and IE, but works fine in chrome and safari.

This is my code:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
});

$(".drop").droppable({
  drop: function (ev, ui) {
    if ($(ev.toElement).hasClass("drop") == true) {
      var widgetId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
      $(ev.toElement).attr("id", "dash_" + widgetId);
      $(ev.toElement).html($(ui.draggable).html());
    }
  }
});
```

Code uploaded at http://www.skmcap63.hostoi.com/box-dashboard/

I need to drag the items from sidebar and drop it into boxes.
Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Not a solution but delete the comma in -> helper: "clone",

Comment: @devo Code uploaded at http://www.skmcap63.hostoi.com/box-dashboard/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *not working*? nothing is working or something isn't working as expected? are you getting any errors? and uut of curiosity, why are you using `ev.toElement`??

Comment: inside the `drop` callback, `this` will refer to the element to which the item is dropped, why are you actually using `ev.toElement` ??

Comment: @T J Using $(ev.target) worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work for u

```
$(".drop").droppable({
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        if ($(ev.target).hasClass("drop") == true) {
            var widgetId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
            $(ev.target).attr("id", "dash_" + widgetId);
            $(ev.target).html($(ui.draggable).html());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain how `ev.target` will do what the OP wants to do?

Comment: @T J, Just refering the link you had posted in the answer,tried out.And it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no [event.toElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534684(v=vs.85).aspx) In firefox, it is [`event.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget).

> The relatedTarget property is used to find the other element, if any, involved in an event. Events like mouseover are oriented around a certain target, but also involve a secondary target, such as the target that is exited as the mouseover event fires for the primary target.

Since different browsers have different properties, You should check which one exists before using it:

```
var el = ev.toElement? ev.toElement: ev.relatedTarget;
```

See [event.toElement in IE8 and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600174/event-toelement-in-ie8-and-firefox) for more info.

Comment: @ T J
If I use event.relatedTarget in place of event.toElement  is not working in chrome also.

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan  Yes, i mentioned *it's firefox only*, so if you simply replace it won't obviously work in other browsers. Different browsers have different properties, Did you go through the question i linked to? You should make sure which one exists before using it.

Answer (score 1):

This code will solve your issue, please note that I didn't tested this in IE because am a `Unixmen`.

```
$(function() {
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
    });

    $(".drop").droppable({
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            var el = ev.toElement? ev.toElement: ev.target;
            if ($(el).hasClass("drop") == true) {
                var widgetId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
                $(el).attr("id", "dash_" + widgetId);
                $(el).html($(ui.draggable).html());
            } 
        }
    });
});
```