# Draggable <div> doesn't return to its original size after release in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Take this draggable . It returns to its original size after releasing it (+ mouse movement) in Chrome but doesn't do so in Firefox.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="drag"></div>
</div>


$(".drag").draggable({
    revert: true,
    containment: "#container"
});

.drag:hover {
width: 100px;
height: 90px;
margin-left: -5px;
margin-top: -7px;
line-height: 62px;
}

.drag {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding:0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 51%;
    top: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

div#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Why is Firefox behaving like this and is there any fix possible?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5940yga/1/)**

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830615/jquery-drag-and-drop-not-working-in-firefox-works-fine-in-chrome-and-safari

Comment: In Firefox, I get the same result as in Chrome. The size comes back to normal if I move my mouse after releasing it: http://jsfiddle.net/wtLx524g/ What version of Firefox are you on? I'm on `36.0.1`

Comment: Same version. Your example works for me too. The difference is that in your example, different jquery-ui is used. That seems to be causing this strange behavior.

Comment: Maybe, what happens if you use that version?

Comment: hover over -> changes size,

drag it,
release and move pointer away -> retains size instead of reverting to initial one

Answer (score 0):

**Works with jQuery UI 1.9.2. on Firefox. This will give you more control over `draggable` behaiour.**

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    revert: function (valid) {
        if (valid) {
            //Dropped in a valid location
        } else {
            //Dropped in an invalid location
        }
        return valid;
    },
    containment: "#container"
});
```

Wokring fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/wtLx524g/1/